# matlab image: return pixel values along the boundingbox in an image?

Tags: image-processing, pixel, matlab

So, I have an RGB image and I've put a rectangle (boundingbox) around an area of the image. However, I can't get the pixel values along the perimeter of this rectangle.

I've tried looking into the function `regionprops` but didn't find anything useful.

I thought I could obtain pixel values from knowing the list of `(x,y)` points along the boundingbox ( `x_init`, `y_init`, `x_width`, `y_width`) but there's no specific function for that. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a specific function in the image processing toolbox for this, but the function you are describing is simple enough to implement yourself:

```
function pixel_vals = boundingboxPixels(img, x_init, y_init, x_width, y_width)

    if x_init > size(img,2) 
        error('x_init lies outside the bounds of the image.'); end
    if y_init > size(img,1)
        error('y_init lies outside the bounds of the image.'); end

    if y_init+y_width > size(img,1) || x_init+x_width > size(img,2) || ...
       x_init < 1 || y_init < 1
        warning([...
            'Given rectangle partially falls outside image. ',... 
            'Resizing rectangle...']);
    end

    x_min   = max(1, uint16(x_init));
    y_min   = max(1, uint16(y_init));
    x_max   = min(size(img,2), x_min+uint16(x_width));
    y_max   = min(size(img,1), y_min+uint16(y_width));
    x_range = x_min : x_max;
    y_range = y_min : y_max;

    Upper = img( x_range, y_min  , :);
    Left  = img(   x_min, y_range, :);
    Right = img(   x_max, y_range, :);
    Lower = img( x_range, y_max  , :);

    pixel_vals = [...
       Upper
       permute(Left, [2 1 3]) 
       permute(Right, [2 1 3])
       Lower];

end
```

Comment: so i subbed 'img' with the pixel matrix of my image

Comment: but there was a error for 
-> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Comment: so i need to do a for loop for Upper, Left, Right, Lower?

is there an easier way to process it?

Comment: i actually drew the bounding box on the image and its doesn't look like it's outside the image.

Comment: @user1715908: OK, look at the latest edit. Perhaps your bounding box is not constrained to pixels but goes sub-pixel (e.g., `x_init = 104.14253...`). Try the latest code. If it fails, post the values of your bounding box, and the size of your image.

Comment: error at the line: pixel_vals = [Upper; Left; Right; Lower];

??? Error using ==> vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

[x_init y_init x_width y_width] = [114.5000   62.5000   69.0000  117.0000]

size of image = [ 225   300     3]

Comment: @user1715908: yes, it's as I thought -- the boundingbox is non-integer. Well, I fixed that, but now the `cat` problem. Can you post the sizes of `Upper`, `Right`, `Lower`, `Left` as they are created?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: I just realized -- I missed a `permute` for the `Left` and `Right` matrices. Should work now :)

Comment: realised my main confusion was that I didn't understand coordinates on the plot is the same as coordinates for pixel allocations :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For any other refer to this question,i had same problem and used Rody Oldenhuis method,but it did not work well in my condition.

you can use matlab built in functions for this :

```
  imgRect=getrect;//get a rectangle region in image
  cropedImg=imcrop(orgImg,[xtopleft ytopleft width height]);//in croppedImg you have the value of specified region
```